# Java declaration sequence causes runtime exception

Tags: java

I am writing JDBC, and wonder will connection get closed before prepared statement cause error and why?

```
public void Delete(){
    Connection conn = DBconn.getConn();
    String sql = "delete from person where name =?";
    PreparedStatement ps = null;

    try{
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, name);
        ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("删除失败");
    } finally {
       try{
           if(ps!=null){
               ps.close();
           }
           if(conn!=null){
               conn.close();
           }
       } catch(Exception ex){
           System.out.println("删除关闭失败");
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "will connection get closed before preparedstatement"? The code you've written closes the PreparedStatement first... although with Java 7, you'd be better off with a try-with-resources statement anyway.

Comment: Can post stacke trace of the exception?

Comment: plz provide fully stacktrace

Comment: Do you want to know?:If any error(Exception) occure during the execution of `preparedStatement` will the system automatically close the connection and why?

Answer (score 0):

According to [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close%28%29)

> Calling the method close on a Statement object that is already closed
>   has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

After establish the connection with the Database

```
   Connection conn = DBconn.getConn();
```

if this line provoke a NullpointerException **ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);** it´s because the conn is null so when you exception will be throw, after the catch will pass for your finally and because the conn is null, you dont have to close the connection.
 In the other hand if the connection it´s ok and you receive a **SQLException** or **SQLFeatureNotSupportedException** then you after being catch for you Exception net, your will pass for your finally again and this time because you conn is created you will close.

So basically yes, your connection always will be released.

Answer (score 0):

The days of JDBC's verbosity are over:

```
try (Connection conn = DBconn.getConn()) {
    String sql = "delete from person where name = ?";
    try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        ps.setString(1, name);
        ps.executeUpdate();
    }
} catch (Exception ex){
    System.out.println("删除失败");
}
```

Try with resources will close automatically.
However your code was working too. Only the connection might require attention. If you are using an embedded database under certain constellation (you would know about) one should not close the connection.